# Include external CSS and JS for Accelerated Mobile Pages?

Tags: javascript, css, accelerated-mobile-page

I am newly trying AMP for existing website. So I read the restrictions in creating a new AMP Page which means creating a new AMP Page. But the AMP Engineers telling that you can also include AMP for the existing website.

Yeah now I started doing AMP with an existing website. At the point I am facing lot of issues while AMP validations by adding `#development=`1 this command at the end of the URL to validate.

The Engineers telling that AMP will help the mobile pages to accelerate pretty much speedy. But I tried for Desktop also. Its working.

But now I am facing the biggest problem. I cannot write CSS more than `50KB` and also I want to use external CSS.

The answer would be appreciable, Thank you.

Comment: AMP pages are styled with CSS, but you can’t reference external stylesheets. All styles must live in the head of the document. See the docs for reference: https://www.ampproject.org/docs/design/responsive/style_pages

Comment: Yeah that I read in their official page. But for me the file size looking huge. so it's says that your file must be 50KB. What I will do now? @Sirence

Comment: Yes, your css needs to be less than 50kb. But that should be plenty if you minimise your css- remember that your page needs to be mobile first. Even big news sites like the verge or gigantic e-commerce sites such as AliExpress use less than 50kb css for their amp, so you should not need any more than they do.

Comment: so there is no other way to inject my files ? @Sirence

Comment: Well, you could just copy the css from the files to your css (as long as you stay under 50kb) - but do remember the point of amp is to keep the mobile sites slim and fast. The more css you add, the more the purpose of amp is negated.

Comment: Also note that AMP will only be served on mobile devices, so phones and tablets. If you have CSS that is specific for desktop, that can be removed from the AMP CSS. And yes, it must be below 50kb, there's no way around it.

Comment: Accelerated mobile app have their own component
https://ampbyexample.com/#introduction

you have to define css in head section.  the main objective of AMP to make your mobile site fast and its works for desktop also. here you see AMP templates
https://www.ampstart.com/

Comment: @RakeshKumar I am not doing any new template. I am working on the existing one

Comment: @VJR Yes I know its just for reference how to use css and js. we cannot included external css in AMP

Comment: @RakeshKumar can i write multiple  <style amp-custom> blblblblblablalbal </style>  <style amp-custom> blblblblblablalbal </style>  <style amp-custom> blblblblblablalbal </style> like this?

Comment: @VJR You may include 1 <style> tag in the <head> of the DOM. You must append amp-custom to the <style> tag like this: <style amp-custom>your style rules here</style>